# Translate my app to Hungarian

Tags: android

I develop an application in english and for a client, i must to translate some text in hungarian. 
I've got a menu.xml files in values folder and i create a new menu.xml in values-hu folder. I start my phone and i select Magyar language. The good language is selected and i see the text in hungarian... well almost!

In my menu.xml, i've this text : Információ and on my screen phone : Inform∂ciciy, why ?

I use Android 2.3 on my phone and my application supports Android 2.1 minimum. I can change the encoding of my menu.xml file but ISO is not agree by eclipse.

Comment: You don't write which encoding you use, but that you can change to ISO. How about utf-8?

Comment: Sorry, i use utf-8 encoding by default. It doesn't work. I try to replace by ISO 8859-16 but eclipse doesn't like this value and does'nt want to save my file...

Comment: It's strange, the test appears normal in dialog box but in all TextView, characters are changed by itself. á replace to ∂ / ó replace to y,... i don't undertand what i miss :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the preferences in eclipse - **Window->Preferences->XML->XML Files**

EDIT (Actual solution):
This is because the android font doesn't support these characters. You can try register your own font and set it to your textviews. I think I had this kind of problem and I ended up with a CustomTextView where the TextView is created with custom Typeface

Comment: Thanks, eclipse save my file now but when i change the value in the xml header, i've this error : Invalid encoding name: "ISO 8859-16"

Comment: inst it ISO-8859-16 - with a dash

Comment: It's ISO-8859-2 for hungarian characters but i've this error when i setup this value : Error parsing XML: unknown encoding. ISO-8859-1 works but all caracters were always strange.

Comment: what if you leave the layout files with utf-8 encoding? I'm working with german symbols, ISO-8859-1 is used only when have to deal with http requests. All my layout files have utf-8 encoding

Comment: It don't seem to be an encoding problem. The text appears normal in dialog box but in all TextView, characters are changed by itself. á replace to ∂ / ó replace to y,... i don't undertand what i miss :( i set utf-8 encoding finally.

Comment: I guess this is because the android font doesn't support this characters. You can try register your own font and set it to your textviews. I think I had this kind of problem and I ended up with a CustomTextView where the TextView is created with custom Typeface

Comment: Of course ! I use a custom font and this font doesn't support these characters. I've removed my font and it works now, thank you !