# Android - Parsing xml with russian words(encoding)

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, encoding

I parse xml file in android. I copypasted example...
It works with english words, but I need to get it working with russian words (it's not working with russion words - without exception - simple bad encoding).
I tried to add this

```
InputSource is = new InputSource();
is.setEncoding("UTF_8"); //add this
is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
doc = db.parse(is);
```

It didn't helped me not a little
Xml is in `utf-8` encoding. I think, my app translates words in utf-8 to windows1252...
Can somebody please help?

Thanks for edit!)

Example with sourcecode - http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: can you post more of your code? Where is the String `xml` filled up? Where is the XML file located? Show us more of what you're doing now, to let us help you.

Comment: I add in question link. It's example. I copypast it's all without any sirious edit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple.
I get answer from http://forum.sources.ru/index.php?showtopic=354149&st=15&#entry3106098
In English:
My app get word from xml in bad encoding!

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                line = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, "UTF-8");
```

Simple, I must add encoding in moment, when i get word!

Answer (score 0):

try using `ISO-8859-5` encoding instead of `UTF-8` (also in your post it's written UTF**_**8 - are you sure about that??? )

Comment: I read on android site, that UTF_8 - is correct. But i try utf-8,UTF-8, UTF_8, utf_8))))

Comment: Ok, did you try the ISO-8859-5

Comment: I change oly in .java is.setEncoding("ISO-8859-5"); Don't change in xml. It's not work. In xml i can change only tomorrow)

Comment: can you read this? http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%8F%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%8B in down. I get - windows1251 to windows 1252

Comment: sorry i get like utf-8 to windows 1252

Comment: well, check this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243731/translate-my-app-to-hungarian/8244281#8244281 , you may not set the correct encoding in eclipse or if you use custom font, it may not support Cyrillic letters